# CPU speed related with disk io?

Tags: linux, raid, network-attached-storage, synology

I planning to purchase a NAS.
https://www.synology.com/en-global/products/RS815+#overview
According their site say, speed was only 398MB/s read and 361MB/s in writing.
What I going to do is I'll put 4TBx4nos as Raid 10. Suppose to be fast multiply by 4 in read and 2 in write. Plus I will make link aggregation four 1Gbe network. So it suppose to be maximum 4Gbe network.

So I think i should get more than their mention I think.

Their CPU is quad-core CPU running at 2.4 GHz.

Is there any issue CPU was limit to rest things. Like even I can put SFP+ 10Gbe link. Speed won't increase?

Answer (score 8):

LACP always helps with redundancy but isn't your panacea for performance.

https://thenetworkway.wordpress.com/2015/05/01/an-overview-of-link-aggregation-and-lacp/

TL;DR: You really need multiple TCP connections to get performance boost, and this isn't what's always possible... SMB can do that "automagically" so you either LACP or SMB Multichannel but say for iSCSI you need both target and initiator support so-called "multiple connections per session".

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/lacp-vs-mpio-on-windows-platform-which-one-is-better-in-terms-of-redundancy-and-speed-in-this-case-2

http://scst.sourceforge.net/mc_s.html

I'd strongly suggest to stick with SMB Multichannel for SMB and with MPIO for iSCSI.

Comment: Seconding that - load balancing with LACP makes it much harder to saturate the links.